# Clone Doctrine Entity keep relations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to move items from one EntityManager to another one (like some kind of data migration), so I want to create every related Entity if it doesn't exist and reuse the ones that exist.

I've read everywhere to use `clone $myEntity` but that won't work.

```
        $query = $fromEm->createQuery('SELECT u FROM AutocasionUserBundle:User u');
        $iterable = $query->iterate();

        foreach ($iterable as $user) {
            $newUser = clone $user[0];
            $fromEm->detach($user[0]);
            $toEm->persist($newUser);
            $toEm->flush();
        }
```

I've also tried to detach $newUser, unsetting my id in `__clone()` magic method but I keep getting errors like this:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  Notice: Undefined index: 000000002a39ac5d0000000077bcb768
```

In this case, `User` has a relationship with an entity called `Source` I want to keep that relation because the `Source` ids exist in my target EntityManager, so `User1->Source1` should now be `User2->Source1` no id reset in here...

Comment: I wouldn't think you need the `[0]` I haven't used doctrine in a minute though.

Comment: Yeah, `$user` is an array (so `$iterable` is an array of arrays), I need to get the object in order to use it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I understand what you are trying to achieve. If you move the user over to a new EntityManager and thus creating User2 shouldn't this also affect the Source, meaning just as User2 is a copy of User1 you will get a Source2 which is an exact copy of Source1? Are both EntityManagers operating on the same database or different ones?